# How to avoid VSCode TypeScript auto import from index.ts on the same level

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

There is folder:

- bar.ts
- foo.ts
- index.ts

index.ts:

```
export * from './bar.ts';
export * from './foo.ts';
```

bar.ts:

```
export const BAR = 1;
```

foo.ts:

```
export const FOO = 2;
```

When I want to import BAR in foo.ts vscode creates auto import:

```
import { BAR } from '.';
```

The question is, how to force vscode to avoid '.' auto imports, to make this be like this:

```
import { BAR } from './bar'; // Correct.
```

**Only when I want to import file that is on the same level**

Is there any option/extension in vscode for such case?

Comment: The index file exists to make imports simpler. Why would you want to ignore it? Also, why don't you remove it, if you don't like it. And third: vscode suggests 2 imports when it recognizes a type: one from the index file and one from the actual file. Use the second suggestion for your import.

Comment: I want to ignore it only when it is on the same level with source file, because in some cases it can cause circular reference (Even found an issue for similar case today: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45953). I don’t want to remove it because I want to make my imports simpler, I have imports not only in files that are on the same level with index.ts, this structure with 3 files is just an example. And also vscode doesn’t suggest 2 imports, it’s only suggest “.” by default, maybe you are using some extension. @MikeLischke

Comment: Yeah this is very annoying to work with if you are blazing through code and accidentally add an import with "." or even ".." it just messes up bundles and builds.
It's not about simplicity, it's about the code actually working afterwards